# php - Fatal error: Class 'OAuth' not found in

Tags: php, oauth, ubuntu-14.04

My OAuth extension(extension=oauth.so) is present in php.ini and I am able to see it when I give "php -m". I have also made sure that oauth.so file is present in /usr/lib/php5/20121212/. Also given this path in php.ini for include_path variable- include_path = ".:/usr/lib/php5/20121212"

Even though my php application throws this error- `Fatal error: Class 'OAuth' not found in /x/y/z.php on line 30`

I tried running the php file in server(ubuntu 14.04). This time it said `"Failed loading oauth:  oauth: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"`

What could be the reason for the failure of oauth loading. Couldn't proceed further.

Thanks in Advance!